# Form of a general solution to an equilibrium equation of elasticity in terms of displacement vectors

Tags: vectors, elasticity

In the theory of elasticity, when the deformation of body is not induced by body forces, but by forces applied to its surface. The equation of equilibrium in terms of the displacement vector, $\mathbf{u}$, can be expressed as follows:
$$
(1 - 2 \sigma) \Delta \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{\nabla} (\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{u}) = 0
 $$
where $\sigma$ is Poisson's ratio, $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator, $\mathbf{\nabla}$ is the gradient operator and $\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot$ is the divergence operator.

Now, in the book of Theory of Elasticity written by Landau and Lifshitz, when they try to calculate the equilibrium of an elastic medium bounded by a plane at Section 8 of Chapter 1, they propose that, for $\mathbf{u}$ satisfying the first equation, there is a solution of this equation in the following form:

$$
\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{\nabla} \phi
$$

where $\phi$ is some scalar and $\mathbf{f}$ satisfies $\Delta \mathbf{f} = 0$.

But, at the same book, at Problem 10 of Section 7 of Chapter 1, they propose that it is natural to seek a solution of the 1st equation by the following way:
$$
\mathbf{u} = \Delta \mathbf{w} + A \mathbf{\nabla} (\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{w})
$$
where $\mathbf{w}$ is some vector and $A$ should be some constant.

I would like to know how to prove that the 2nd and 3rd equations would be a form of the general solution of the 1st equation?
I feel that the 2nd equation is missing some constant.

**Edit.1**
The decomposition of $\mathbf{u}$ reminds me of the Helmholtz decomposition. But, clearly, they have some differences.

Comment: The missing constant will be explained by boundary conditions. For example, imagine an infinite medium where you want the displacement to vanish at infinity.

Comment: Hi, @kricheli, It seems that $\mathbf{u}$ can be decomposed to a sum of a gradient and something (a vector $\mathbf{f}$ in the first case, and a Laplacian in the second case), which reminds me the Helmholtz decomposition. But how to prove that the $\mathbf{u}$ can be decomposed in such ways?